# Google Script to empty emails in trash folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-api

I was using the below google app script to delete emails automatically from my trash folder. for some reason, this is no longer deleting the emails however the trigger dashboard shows the script executed successfully. can someone help to modify the script ? thanks in advance.

```
function removeMyTest2() {
var mymail = "me";
var mylabel = "del";
var permanentlyRemoveMyLabel = true;
var pageToken;
do {
    var threadList = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {
    q: 'in:trash' + mylabel,
    pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (threadList.threads && threadList.threads.length > 0) {
        threadList.threads.forEach(function(thread) {
        Logger.log('id: %s snippet: %s', thread.id, thread.snippet);
        if (permanentlyRemoveMyLabel) {
            Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(mymail, thread.id);
            Logger.log('id: %s snippet: %s REMOVED', thread.id, thread.snippet);
        }
    });
   }
   pageToken = threadList.nextPageToken;
   } while (pageToken);
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure that they are enabled in your Resource/Advanced Google Services

Comment: this is turned ON for Gmail V1 and the rights was given to the trigger as well. Still this is running the script, bu the email messages are not getting deleted. see below

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I believe you were missing the label key.

```
function removeMyTest2() {
  var pageToken=null;
  do {
    var threadList=Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {q:'in:trash label:del',pageToken:pageToken});
    if (threadList.threads && threadList.threads.length>0) {
      threadList.threads.forEach(function(thread) {
        Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", thread.id);
      });
    }
    pageToken=threadList.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

I tested this with another label and it works fine

I needed this scope: https://mail.google.com/